# How to make animation slower SwiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

```
    Button("forward") {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut.delay(1)) {
            isForward.toggle()
        }
    }
```

I tried to make my animation slower and smoother however the result i got is freezed animation.

My second try was lowering down the delay value to 0.7 but it did not work too.

Answer (score 1):

Change from `.delay` to `.speed` instead. Lower value = slower speed.

```
withAnimation(.easeInOut.speed(0.5)) {
        isForward.toggle()
}
```

Comment: Oh I get it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just wanted to change duration

```
Button("forward") {
    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) {   // << here !!
        isForward.toggle()
    }
}
```